# comparing lines and columns for zero data

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a file containing the following data.

File1:

```
Server counter         1:00 2:00 3:00 4:00
site1 serverdowntime  15     0     3     500
site1 serverdowntimesuc  15     0     3     500

...

site12 serverdowntime   2     7     8      5
site12 serverdowntimesuc   2     7     8      5

...

site50 serverdowntime   2     12     8      45
site50 serverdowntimesuc   2     0     0      45

...

site57 serverdowntime   2     12     8      45
site57 serverdowntimesuc   2     0     0      0
```

Each 2 lines are for the same site. First colum is equipment, second is problem  and the third could contain as many columns for the amount of hours pulled. Im looking for a way to look under the time data and find each two lines that contain only single zeros.

Output after parsing data:

```
site57 serverdowntime   2     12     8      45
site57 serverdowntimesuc   2     0     0      0
site1  serverdowntime   15    0       3     500
site1  serverdowntimesuc 15  0     3    500
site50 serverdowntime   2     12     8      45
site50 serverdowntimesuc   2     0     0      45
```

Comment: only single zeros? line two in your output contains three zeros

Comment: correct i would still like the data from the rest of the columns and their can be as few as one column or 10+ columns of numbers, but lines with a single zero is what im most interested in

Comment: they are also in pairs so i would need both lines even if one only had 0 data in it.

Comment: and first line in each file is `"File1: ... etc"`?

Comment: wrt "single zeros" - you don't show any input with "multiple zeros". Are you really trying to find the numeric value zero rather than cases where zero appears as part of a non-zero number? "10" contains a "single zero" - do you want that printed?

Comment: Please fix your post to show what your files *actually* look like. I already made it into a Markdown code block, but it is difficult to determine what your files looked like. [If you find yourself using `&nbsp;` and `<br>` on Stack Overflow you are probably doing something the hard way.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{next} !(NR%2){line1=$0;next} {$0=line1"\n"$0} /\<0\>/' file
site1 serverdowntime  15    0       3     500
site1 serverdowntimesuc 15  0     3    500
site50 serverdowntime   2     12     8      45
site50 serverdowntimesuc   2     0     0      45
site57 serverdowntime   2     12     8      45
site57 serverdowntimesuc   2     0     0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;/^(\S+)\s.*\n\1/!D;/(^|\n)(\S+\s+){2}[^\n]*\s0(\s+|\n|$)/p;d' file
```

This gets a pair of lines with the first field as key and then searches for a `0` pattern in the 3rd onwards fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '($k)=/^(\w+)/; if (/\b0\b/){ print $v{$k}, $_ }else{ $v{$k}=$_ }' file
```